# Merge pandas data frame based on the ranges between the dates in the another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

```
tariff data

        dt_start    dt_end  energy_fee  parking_fee
    0   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 15:00:00+02:00   0.50    0.50
    1   2020-05-27 15:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 20:00:00+02:00   0.42    0.50
    2   2020-05-27 20:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 21:00:00+02:00   0.16    0.10
    3   2020-05-27 21:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 22:00:00+02:00   0.50    0.50
    4   2020-05-27 22:00:00+02:00   2020-05-28 01:00:00+02:00   0.38    0.32
```

session data

```
    id  dt_start    dt_end  energy
0   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:12:00+02:00   2.00
1   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:25:00+02:00   0.30
2   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:27:00+02:00   4.50
3   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:01:00+02:00   2.03
4   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:26:00+02:00   3.69
```

End outcome what I want is
session data

```
        id  dt_start    dt_end  energy energy_fee   parking_fee
    0   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:12:00+02:00   2.00 0.50   0.50
    1   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:25:00+02:00   0.30 0.50   0.50
    2   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:27:00+02:00   4.50 0.50   0.50
    3   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:01:00+02:00   2.03 0.50   0.50
    4   1   2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00   2020-05-27 13:26:00+02:00   3.69 0.50   0.50
```

I am trying to get energy_fee and parking_fee from the tariff dataset. for the range of dt_start and dt_end in the session dataset.

Example: session['dt_start '][0] and session['dt_end'][0] falls in the interval of tarrif['dt_start'][0] and tarrif['dt_end'][0]. I want to get the energy_fee and parking_fee.

Some context:
Tarrif dataset has the ranges of dt_start and dt_end with energy fee and parking fee. I have to calculate the cost of energy and parking for the dt_start and dt_end of sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge both dataframes:

```
df_session.reset_index().merge(df_tariff, on=['dt_start', 'dt_end'], how='left').set_index('index')
```

Comment: The dataframe output is energy_fee and parking_fee output is NaN. I tried 'right' and 'outer' for how, but no luck                                                          id dt_start dt_end energy energy_fee parking_fee
index      
0 1 2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00 2020-05-27 13:12:00+02:00 2.00 NaN NaN
1 1 2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00 2020-05-27 13:25:00+02:00 0.30 NaN NaN
2 1 2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00 2020-05-27 13:27:00+02:00 4.50 NaN NaN
3 1 2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00 2020-05-27 13:01:00+02:00 2.03 NaN NaN
4 1 2020-05-27 13:00:00+02:00 2020-05-27 13:26:00+02:00 3.69 NaN NaN

Comment: Do you want to merge on row to row basis or on overlapping intervalls?

Comment: There is no common column to merge here. The thing is the columns dt_start and st_end are with the same name, but the values in them are not of the same values. Tariff data has ranges of time. In session data, it is the session used.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a solution to this by combining pandas with sqlite3.

I understood that the join I wanted to make on the data is a cross join as there is no common column on which I can merge tables. Therefore, I decided to import my CSV to sqlite3 DB and perform the cross join. AS sqlite3 has better ways to perform cross join than compared to what pandas have to offer.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("./data/output/library.db")
session.to_sql('session', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace' )
tarrif.to_sql('tarrif', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace') 

qry = '''
select s.id, s.energy, s.minutes,t.energy_fee, t.parking_fee
from session s join tarrif t
WHERE (s.dt_start between t.dt_start and t.dt_end)
and (s.dt_end between t.dt_start and t.dt_end)'''

df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)
```